# How to do median filter on an indexed image using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

`medfilt2(img)` doesn't take a `map` as parameter,

so I don't think it can work well with indexed image,

how do I impelemnt an median filter that can be used to process indexed images?

Answer (score 3):

From the [`medfilt2` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/medfilt2.html):

`B = medfilt2(A, 'indexed', ...)` processes A as an indexed image, padding with 0s if the class of A is uint8, or 1s if the class of A is double.

Comment: But we need to **2** variables to represent an indexed image:`[X,map]`,how can it be done with a single `A` ?

Comment: The map should be the same as for original image. You need it only to show the image in proper colors.